# Why does interp function give me error?

Tags: r, interpolation

```
n <- akima :: interp(
            x, y, z, xo = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100), 
            yo = seq(min(y), max(y), length = 100),
            linear = TRUE, extrap = FALSE,
            duplicate = "error", dupfun = NULL, 
            ncp = NULL)
```

But it gives:

```
Error in interp.old(x, y, z, xo = xo, yo = yo, ncp = 0, extrap = extrap,  : 
missing values and Infs not allowed
```

Let's check:
`is.na(x), is.na(y), is.na(z)` all are FALSE

```
str(x)
num [1:1398] 1.62 1.62 1.62 1.62 1.63 1.63 1.63 1.63 1.63 1.63 ...

str(y)
num [1:1398] 2993 2998 3001 3005 2993 ...

str(z)
'data.frame':   1398 obs. of  1 variable:
$ V1: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 ...
```

What should I change?

Comment: did you check that `all(is.finite(x))` for `x`,`y`, and `z`? And are you sure you want `z` to be a data.fame? How about using `z$V1` instead to extract the numeric vector?

Comment: Yes,it works fine with z$V1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `z` is a data.frame and `interp` expects a numeric vector. Try using

```
n <- akima::interp(x, y, z$V1, ...)
```